# What is the root path for setting directory in File name for "tfileInput"?

Tags: java, talend

I want to know the location of rootpath of tfileInput  component configuration for file name.So that I can use "./", I want to create a resource directory in the Rootpath, so I could just export the project files in it. Then I would be able to use directly it as:'/Resource/filename.csv' in other machines as well.
Is there any way around to do this or Am I missing something very basic?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `tFileProperties` to get information on the `.` location.

[image]

And it gives me with a 6.5.1 studio :

```
.------------------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+-----+-------------+-----------------------------.
|                                                  tLogRow_1                                                   |
|=-----------------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+-----+-------------+----------------------------=|
|abs_path                            |dirname|basename|mode_string|size |mtime        |mtime_string                 |
|=-----------------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+-----+-------------+----------------------------=|
|<talend_6.5.1_path>\Studio\studio\. |null   |.       |rw         |12288|1558511069179|Wed May 22 09:44:29 CEST 2019|
'------------------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+-----+-------------+-----------------------------'
```

With this, you can easily start using the correct path.
Note that if you have a TAC to install the process on a server, the result my differ.

Based on that, I would suggest to use a context value for the `rootPath` and always use absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to launch your Job from Talend, ".\" referes to your Workspace.

If you desire to launch your Job builded (.bat or .sh), ".\" referes to the path where your builded Job is localized.

Hence, ".\Resource\filename.csv" folder has to be localized either in your Talend workspace (relatively to your TOS_DI-win-xXX_XX.exe), or in the same path of your builded Job.

Hope this can be heplful for you. Don't hesitate if you need more help.